# Multithreaded IP scanner

Tags: c, multithreading, networking

In order to scan through a range of IP's with multiple threads I decided that I would split the work by assigning different threads different ranges of IP addresses however I have run into the problem of how do I split different ranges. If I were doing a similar program but instead I was going through an Array I would do something like this:

```
void *thread()
{
    for(;x < threadRange ;x++)
    {
            arr[x] = <insert var here>;
    }
    x = threadRange;
    threadRange+=arrSize/threadCount;
}
```

so I guess my question is how do I do this when scanning IP addresses? Is there anyway to do this type of math with an IP address?

Comment: If you have `X` number of addresses, and `Y` number of threads, lets each thread handle `X / Y` number of addresses.

Comment: Since IP address ranges are 32-bit binary numbers, and a network is a number which is a poser of 2, it is easy to further divide (subnet) a network into subnets by powers of 2. If you need help with subnetting, see this great answer: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499

Comment: If you don't want to scan more than one host at a time per thread, you can create standard solutions for a single producer, multiple consumer scenario. Or, you could use a thread pool. BTW: In C++, you shouldn't need any void pointers. Use `std::thread`!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I accidentally tagged it as C++ but I am using c with pthreads to do this.

Comment: @RonMaupin Could you further explain what you mean by this I am really new to network programming and I don't understand how this would help me iterate over a range of IP addresses to scan a network.

Comment: What I mean is that you could easily divide a network into `n` subnets, where `n` is a power of `2`, and scan each one of those with a thread. If you have a fairly standard `/24` network, and you wanted to use eight threads, `8=2^3`, so you add `3` bits to get `/27`, and you scan each of the eight `/27` networks, one in each thread. See the link I provided on how to subnet.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there anyway I can calculate the network address/broadcast address everytime I go and scan the network? In the solution you gave me you would need to know a valid IP address. Most devices on my network have their IP address change every so often.

Comment: The addresses which change (probably due to DHCP) will still be in the same network. You can use any address in the block, along with the mask, to determine everything about the network. IP math only needs those two pieces of information, everything else can be derived from knowing an address and mask.

Comment: @RonMaupin So I can just use any arbitrary IP address for example 192.168.0.1 every time even if it doesn't correspond to any device on the network?

Comment: As long as the IP address is in the network, you can use any address in that network, along with the mask for that network. The easiest thing to do would be to look at the IP address and mask assigned to the interface of your device which is connected to the network. You already have those two pieces of information in your machine.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes but my goal is to scan any network I'm on without having to know those two pieces of information. Much like how Nmap works.

Comment: That does the same thing, it gets the IP address and mask from the interface which is connected to the network. You just need to do that.